# The output of a certain code does not make sense to me

Tags: python

So I followed a code that someone wrote about very beginner stuff with *Python*. The output does not make sense to me.

```
print("Hello World") 
myName = input("What is your name?") 
myVar = input("Enter a number: ")

if(myName == "Bob" and myVar == 0): 
  print("Bob is great.") 
elif(myName == "Joe"): 
  print("Joe is ok.") 
else:             
  print("Hello World")
```

when I run the code in cmd and type Bob and 0, it should say Bob is great. However, this is not the case. Thank you for your help.

Comment: What does it say? What happens?

Comment: The code output
    Hello World

It needed to print out "Bob is great."

Answer (score 3):

The expression

```
myVar == 0
```

will never be `True` because you are comparing a `str` with an `int`. Make sure you convert their input to `int`

```
myVar = int(input("Enter a number: "))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `int(myVar)` as you are trying to compare an int and a string. Otherwise `print "'"+myName+"' '"+myVar+"'"` to get a visual queue.